# what happens when char array is not terminated by a null character in both case when size of array is fixed and when there is no size mentioned?

Tags: arrays, string

I declared two char array both are not terminated by a null character.

Since neither are terminated by a null both should show undefined behaviour.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    char str1[]={'R','O','N'};
    char str2[5]={'R','O','N'};
    printf("String :-%s\n",str1);
    printf("String :-%s\n",str2);
}
```

This is the output I am getting:

> String :-RON
>
> String :-RON

Comment: Both cases exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: If the contents of memory are 0 after the part where the array contents are stored, that gets treated as a null terminator. It depends on how your fields get arranged in memory whether this happens to work or not. And whether your implementation zeroes out memory, dont know if they all do. Working by accident is a kind of undefined behavior.   Btw this should get a language tag, probably C?